# Align the larger text of <option> in a dropdown from right to left in firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dropdown on the right edge of the screen with a large text in the options tag.

In chrome,when we select the dropdown the text i.e options values are automatically aligned from right to left.

[image: Dropdown in Chrome]

But in firefox, the text is getting wrapped on the right side of the screen.

[image: Dropdown in firefox]

I have used the "direction:rtl" for select and "direction:ltr" for option, it solves the problem somehow but it changes the direction of dropdown arrow from left to right.

Is there any way to access the arrow of the select tag.

Thanks.

Comment: That's a browser feature. Can't do anything. `:)` Period.

Comment: @PraveenKumar okay..thanks a lot btw for ur concern :)

Comment: But let's wait and see if there are some experts who can solve this. If not, this will be unanswered. Do you want a rather jQuery solution for this? Using `Select2`? Have a look at http://Select2.github.io. `:)` Lemme know if that suits. I will add that as an answer then.

Comment: @PraveenKumar yeah lets wait if there would be any hack to do it. Btw that JQuery solution for Select is great but can't use it in my project. Thanks a lot :)